# Web2py default app

Tags: dns, dreamhost, web2py

I am planning to publish my site soon on [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) using passenger WSGI as mentioned in the [dreamhost setup documentation](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Web2py).

My issue is that I am wanting www.mydomain.com to go directly to my new application, instead of needing to go to web2py.mydomain.com/MyApp/Default.

What is the best way to solve this issue?  Do I use DNS redirects or can this be done through the web2py configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option available since web2py version 1.83 (Aug 11, 2010):

[Default Application, Controller, and Function](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Default-Application,-Controller-and-Function)
The name of the default application, controller and function can be changed from **init**, **default**, and **index** respectively to another name by setting the appropriate value in routes.py:

```
default_application = "myapp"
default_controller = "admin"
default_function = "start"
```

Comment: i don't get this to work in the current version, i still go to /welcome/default/index

Comment: if routes.py doesn't exist, you have to create it with these 3 lines and restart web2py (if you started web2py from gui window, you have to close it first)

Answer (score 5):

You can in web2py. You have two options:
1) call your app "init"

2) use routes to do the mapping. Create a file web2py/routes.py and in it add

```
routes_in=[('/','/MyApp/default/index')]
```

Comment: i don't get this to work in the current version, i still go to /welcome/default/index

Comment: @RobinManoli What are you currently using?  It worked just fine for me.  I just needed to change MyApp to the name of my app.